# Can't find page request per second statistics for IIS/asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, benchmarking

Does anyone have any literature regarding page requests per second for asp.net (preferably MVC) applications?

I realize it is application specific, but just looking to read up on case studies etc. and expereinces.

Is 1K per second possible?

Answer (score 0):

It could be anywhere from less than one to hundreds of thousands per second.  Hope that helps.

If you need more specific answers, try to include something (anything) about the setup or type of app.  One machine, a farm of 10,000 machines, a simple app serving mostly-static data, a scientific data processing app, etc etc -

Comment: single server performance, for a cms like app. simple key based lookups for db query.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar when I saw this question. But here's a useful blog post I've come across at the same time. [Golden Rule of Web Caching](http://gojko.net/2007/11/29/golden-rule-of-web-caching/) which has some stats which may be relevant for you.

Admittedly, your first request will include the latency of hitting the database, but if you're caching correctly afterwards, you'll get something fairly similar to Gojko's results.

So, in answer, yes. 1k hits per second are definitely achievable.

Another thing I've been trying is using WCAT (Web Capacity Analysis Tool) for testing application performance. Is not difficult to get +1k pages per second from a modest IIS setup if you focus on nice light pages.